# How to use autodetect schema in big query app script to load string type columns as headers in bigquery table?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I have a google script that loads the csv table from cloud storage to big query. It works fine with most tables but when all the columns types are string, the auto detection is not able to find header name and it gives the column as string_01, string_02. Here's is the part of the code.

```
        load.setDestinationTable(tableReference);
        load.setSourceUris([source]);
        load.setSourceFormat('CSV');
        load.setAutodetect(true);
        load.setMaxBadRecords(0);
        load.setWriteDisposition('WRITE_TRUNCATE');
```

Does anyone know what can I add to the code to have the first line be selected as the header for the table. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to add **skip_leading_rows**.

```
load.skipLeadingRows(1)
```

This will let the API know that 1st row is a header and should not be used as part of the "data" import.

Comment: Thanks, but that would just skip the rows not use them as header. Header would still be string0, string1 etc.